# Limiting Subscriptions to be emailed using SSRS

Tags: sql, reporting-services

Currently, our system will do a "foreach" over all Subscriptions which are returned from the ListSubscriptions method of ReportingService and fire a Timed Subscription event so that they receive the report as an email.

In our dev environment, I don't want every subscription of these reports to be sent out when we are testing.

Is there a way I can create a new subscription with my own email address being used so that I receive the report? The temp subscription could then be deleted after sending.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up figuring out how to do this myself

Created a test subscription using 
subId = rs.CreateSubscription()

then deleted it after fireEvent("TimedSubscription", subId)

rs.DeleteSubscription(subId)

Comment: OK, this didn't quite work as when you fire the event, the delete subscription doesn't wait on the event completing. There may be a way to use the async and oncompleted event of fireevent to do this but documentation is pretty sparse.